# How to pass log4j2.configurationFile env variable from maven command

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I want to use a log4j2.xml placed outside my spring-boot app.

when i run using java command with below command it works fine.

```
java -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/Users/ilam/Documents/abc.xml -jar target/myapp.war
```

but when i run

```
mvn -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/Users/ilam/Documents/abc.xml clean spring-boot:run
```

my abc.xml is not used.

passing -Dspring-boot.run.arguments did not help either because it looks like log4j kicks in before spring boot kicks in

1. I don't want to use spring profiles
2. I don't want to touch pom.xml. Basically i don't want touch anything in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**-Dspring-boot.run.arguments** is for program arguments.

You should be using **spring-boot.run.jvmArguments**.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dlog4j2.configurationFile=file:/Users/ilam/Documents/abc.xml"
```